# Form validation for saving before exit

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation

I created a form in asp.net and now I need to add a validation to it, so if any of the fields has been populated and user will try to leave the page, the pop-up will appear asking "Do you want to exit without saving?". Is there a simple way I can to this?

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Damages", FormMethod.Post))        
   {%>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%=Html.LabelFor(model => model.OrderId)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Model.OrderId%>
        </div>  

        ....                              

        <%=Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)%>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onbeforeunload event:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   if( isDirty ) {
      return 'Do you want to exit without saving?';
   }
}
</script>
```

Of course you need to keep track of form field changes and set the isDirty flag accordingly.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx